# Как все числа, которые встречаются в строке, поместить в строку разделив запятой?

Tags: 1с

Водится строка, содержащая буквы, целые неотрицательные числа и
иные символы. Требуется все числа, которые встречаются в строке,
поместить в строку разделив запятой с пробелом. Например, если дана
строка "data 48 call 9 read13 blank0a", то в строке ответ должны
оказаться числа 48, 9, 13 и 0.

Comment: добро пожаловать! приведите свои попытки решения или мысли, как вы думаете это должно выглядеть. Можно показать ваш код или ошибки, которые получаете при исполнении. Дополнить можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1292239/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
Функция ЗадачаСоStackOverflow(ИсходнаяСтрока)

ДлинаИсходнойСтроки = СтрДлина(ИсходнаяСтрока);
Цифры = "0123456789";
РезультирующаяСтрока = "";
ЧислоСтрокой = ""; 

Для НомерСимвола = 1 по ДлинаИсходнойСтроки Цикл
//Считываем очередной символ из исходной строки
СимволИсходнойСтроки = Сред(ИсходнаяСтрока,НомерСимвола,1);   

 Если СтрНайти(Цифры, СимволИсходнойСтроки) <> 0 Тогда
    //Собираем число из цифр в строку
    ЧислоСтрокой = ЧислоСтрокой + СимволИсходнойСтроки; 
 Иначе
 //Очередной символ НЕ число
 //тогда проверяем было ли сформировано число 
 //если да то записываем его в результирующую строку и очищаем его
  Если НЕ ПустаяСтрока(ЧислоСтрокой) Тогда
   РезультирующаяСтрока = РезультирующаяСтрока + ЧислоСтрокой + ", ";  
  ЧислоСтрокой = "";
 КонецЕсли;
КонецЕсли; 

КонецЦикла; 

//уберем лишнюю запятую с пробелом из результирующей строки
РезультирующаяСтрока = 
Лев(РезультирующаяСтрока, СтрДлина(РезультирующаяСтрока)-2);

Возврат  РезультирующаяСтрока;

КонецФункции

Функция ЗадачаСоStackOverflow_2(ИсходнаяСтрока)

 ДлинаИсходнойСтроки  = СтрДлина(ИсходнаяСтрока);
 Цифры                = "0123456789";
 РезультирующаяСтрока = "";
 ЧислоСтрокой         = ""; 

 //[1] Инициализация пустой строкой, при первом заходе пригодится
 ЗапятаяСПробелом     = "";

 Для НомерСимвола = 1 по ДлинаИсходнойСтроки Цикл  
  СимволИсходнойСтроки = Сред(ИсходнаяСтрока, НомерСимвола, 1);   

  Если СтрНайти(Цифры, СимволИсходнойСтроки) <> 0 Тогда    
   ЧислоСтрокой = ЧислоСтрокой + СимволИсходнойСтроки; 
  Иначе   
   Если НЕ ПустаяСтрока(ЧислоСтрокой) Тогда
    //[2] Поменяем форимрование итоговой строки
    //теперь добавляем ее перед числовой строкой
    РезультирующаяСтрока = РезультирующаяСтрока + ЗапятаяСПробелом + ЧислоСтрокой;  
    ЧислоСтрокой = "";
    //[3] Начиная со второго прохода это запятая с пробелом
    ЗапятаяСПробелом = ", ";
   КонецЕсли;
  КонецЕсли; 

 КонецЦикла; 

 //Для случая когда строка заканчивается числом
 Если НЕ ПустаяСтрока(ЧислоСтрокой) Тогда
  РезультирующаяСтрока = РезультирующаяСтрока + ЗапятаяСПробелом + ЧислоСтрокой;  
 КонецЕсли;


 Возврат РезультирующаяСтрока;

КонецФункции 

Функция ЗадачаСоStackOverflow_3(ИсходнаяСтрока)
 
 ДлинаИсходнойСтроки  = СтрДлина(ИсходнаяСтрока);
 Цифры                = "0123456789";
 РезультирующаяСтрока = "";
 ЧислоСтрокой         = ""; 
 
 //[1] Теперь возмем массив куда будем совать найденные числа
 МассивНайденныхЧисел = Новый Массив();

 Для НомерСимвола = 1 по ДлинаИсходнойСтроки Цикл  
  СимволИсходнойСтроки = Сред(ИсходнаяСтрока, НомерСимвола, 1);     

  Если СтрНайти(Цифры, СимволИсходнойСтроки) <> 0 Тогда    
   
   ЧислоСтрокой = ЧислоСтрокой + СимволИсходнойСтроки; 
  Иначе
   Если НЕ ПустаяСтрока(ЧислоСтрокой) Тогда
    //[2] Нашли - добавили
    МассивНайденныхЧисел.Добавить(ЧислоСтрокой);
    ЧислоСтрокой = "";
   КонецЕсли;    
  КонецЕсли; 
 КонецЦикла;

 //Если Строка заканчивается "числом"
 Если НЕ ПустаяСтрока(ЧислоСтрокой) Тогда    
   МассивНайденныхЧисел.Добавить(ЧислоСтрокой);    
 КонецЕсли;  

 //[3] Отправили массив в матрицу к нео - получили запятые на своих местах (сработает с 8.3.6)
 РезультирующаяСтрока = СтрСоединить(МассивНайденныхЧисел, ", ");

 Возврат РезультирующаяСтрока;

КонецФункции
```

Comment: Можно использовать флаг; ПредСимволЦифра = Ложь; и при добавлении символа в результирующую строку менять его; и так добавлять ", "

Comment: Зачем же так усложнять? Если хочется не плодить лишних запятых что бы их потом не удалять, сделать это можно и без флагов с условиями...

Comment: Ну скажем в приведенном коде, - в случае если исходная строка будет содержать всего один символ; После цикла РезультирующаяСтрока = "1" превратится в "" как раз из-за //уберем лишнюю запятую с пробелом из результирующей строки

Comment: Вы не поняли мой посыл. Что бы сформировать строку сразу с "хорошими" запятыми, никакие флаги не нужны, это усложнение... И в алгоритме действительно была проблема, более принципиальная чем запятая))) добавил ещё два способа решения, без флагов и прочих нагромождений